# Why does react input checkbox not check when onChange handler is setting state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React app with some check boxes that were mapped out that don't check anymore when the onChange handler function sets a state. However, the checkboxes do work when I am not setting a state without arrays e.g. setState("it works"). But, they don't work when I am setting a state with arrays e.g. setState([...array, value]) and instead remain unchecked. The console.log for e.target.checked remains true and visually is unchecked when I click the checkbox/trigger the onChange handler function. The checkbox works when I don't setState at all. The following is my code snippet, I don't think I am understanding why this is happening.

```
export default function ReserveModal({ className, openModal }) {      
      const [roomsData, setRoomsData] = useState([]);
      const [selectedRooms, setSelectedRooms] = useState([]);}

      const handleSelect = (e) => {
        const checked = e.target.checked;
        const value = e.target.value;
        setSelectedRooms(
          checked
            ? [...selectedRooms, value]
            : selectedRooms.filter((item) => item !== value)
       );
      };
    
      return (
       <div className={styles.roomNumbers}>
          {roomsData.map((roomNumber) => {
            return (
              <div key={uuidv4()} className={styles.rooms}>
                <label htmlFor="roomNumber">{roomNumber.number}</label>
                <input value={roomNumber.number} name="roomNumber" id="roomNumber" type="checkbox" onClick={handleSelect} />
              </div>
            );
          })}
       </div>
);
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting `e.target.value` to be? Did you mean to use `e.target.name`?

Comment: Also a FYI. Don't use UUIDs for `key`s. The keys are used internally by react for optimization. You will get unexpected results if you use random keys like that and then update your array. You are supposed to build the `id` from unique data in the array element.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I just edited the code I put in. I am iterating through an array of objects and expecting e.target.value to return the roomNumber.number value, which it does when I console.log it. So I wanted to set that to an array with useState but the checkbox doesn't work when I do that.

Comment: How would you suggest to build my key instead of using uuid? I'm relatively new and heard that was one way to build your key.

Comment: You should probably use the `checked` attribute of the input. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

Comment: @importTurtle If you have a static array (it never changes) you can use the array index as key. If not you should use something that is unique to that element. Like the roomNumber or whatever you store in it. If no one key is unique, you can combine different keys to make a unique id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually set the `checked` attribute of the input. I think something like this should work:

```js
export default function ReserveModal({ className, openModal }) {      
      const [roomsData, setRoomsData] = useState([]);
      const [selectedRooms, setSelectedRooms] = useState([]);}

      const handleSelect = (e) => {
        const checked = e.target.checked;
        const value = e.target.value;
        setSelectedRooms(
          checked
            ? [...selectedRooms, value]
            : selectedRooms.filter((item) => item !== value)
       );
      };
    
      return (
       <div className={styles.roomNumbers}>
          {roomsData.map((roomNumber) => {
            return (
              <div key={uuidv4()} className={styles.rooms}>
                <label htmlFor="roomNumber">{roomNumber.number}</label>
                <input checked={selectedRooms.includes(roomNumber.number)} value={roomNumber.number} name="roomNumber" id="roomNumber" type="checkbox" onClick={handleSelect} />
              </div>
            );
          })}
       </div>
);
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me and when I console.log e.target.checked it's still always true whenever I click the checkbox. I also get an error from react devtools backend "You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultChecked`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.". So I tried changing onClick to onChange and checked to defaultChecked and I am still getting true in console.log and an unticked checkbox no matter how many times I clicked.

Comment: I figured it out after rewriting the code and your solution with the checked attribute fixed it, thanks everyone for your contributions